# Инфоблок, тип свойства "привязка к разделам инфоблока"

Tags: cms, битрикс

Bitrix,

свойство инфоблока привязано к разделам другого инфоблока.
В $arResult приходит ID привязанного раздела.

А я бы хотел получить все элементы этого раздела.

Что для этого нужно сделать?

Comment: Не стоит многократно дублировать вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Зная ID раздела можно получить список элементов используя метод `GetList` класса `CIBlockElement`. Вам нужно только передать ID раздела в фильтр.
Сделать это можно как-то так:

```
<?php
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>IBLOCK_ID, "ACTIVE"=>"Y", "SECTION_ID"=>ID_пришедший_в_$arResult);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50), $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){ 
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    print_r($arFields);
}
?>
```

Подробнее почитайте в [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php)

[Документация API](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/) хоть и не достаточно полная, но ответы на 75% вопросов содержит. И не бойтесь гуглить, она хорошо проиндексирована. Да и на форумах 1С-Битрикс вопрос "Получить список элементов по ID раздела" освещен неоднократно.